# Unable to debug some aspx pages in ASP application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a classic ASP website running on IIS. I opened it with VS 2015 (Open website in File menu) and saved the solution (when opening it it said this is a precompiled website - whatever that means). Then I attached to process to debug it.

Now, the breakpoints I placed are hit on some of the .aspx pages, and not on others. Any idea why this might be the case? I checked the webconfig and it has debug option set to true. Probably some PDB files are missing. People suggest to rebuild the website, but when I click build or rebuild solution, the process completes immediately with success, so I doubt anything was recompiled at all.

I can modify the code of those pages and the IIS recompiles them on the next request, but not sure why the breakpoints don't get hit there. They obviously are once I put something like Debugger.Launch() in my code, but it's not what I want.

I'm no expert so I'd be grateful if you could help me out with this.

Comment: Could you share a screen shot about the warning/error "it said this is a precompiled website", if it works well after you rebuild it, one possible reason is that you have changed certain files' location or the code, for example, you said that you save the solution file, whether it is related to the solution files(.sln) you have saved manually? The default web site project has two different folders save the project files. So you could try to create a new blank web site, and then save all project files to this new blank project. Or you could find differences if debug normally.

Comment: For the issue "breakpoint is not hit", please check the detailed output messages in the output or Error list window. Please also enable the Microsoft symbol server under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols, please also disable the option "Require source files to exactly match the original version" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->General.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT If I rebuild the solution, nothing changes and the breakpoints still don't get hit. Once I click rebuild it says immediately in the console that the rebuild completed, so I doubt anything was rebuilt at all.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I've enabled and disabled the options you mentioned, still nothing. In the output window it says (once I start debugging): 'w3wp.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Microsoft Active Server Pages)'.

Comment: Click Build->Configuration manage, please make sure you enable the "build" option for all your projects, and then clean and rebuild the whole solution, click save all, re-debug it again.

Comment: this can happen when PDB files are out of sync with current compiling files. so you need to rebuilt the whole application

Comment: @user216094, would you please let us know the latest information? Whether this issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Precompiled website means it improves performance on some ASP.NET websites. It can be used to optimize static sites. We explore strategies for other types of sites. This speeds up the first access to pages in your site. And if you want the faster option for the site once deployed, please consider "site precompilation." Let's assume your site is high-volume, popular and important. It is important that the site respond instantly when a customer visits.

Hope this is helpful.